# Concordant Crossword: A MtG crossword

Tags: crosswords, magic-the-gathering

Enjoy this relatively easy Mtg themed crossword. All entries are card names (punctuation and spaces removed but otherwise preserved). Yes some of them are going to be hard to get in a vacuum, but fill in the surrounding entries and that should help. GL HF!

[image]

### Horizontal

$1$. I forget what set this monkey was from...maybe Iraqi Nights?
$7$. A one-time color shifting of 16-across.
$10$. The perfectly average way to say no.
$12$. 17,18,19, aaaand 20! Got a stifle?
$13$. The latest in a line of identical elves stretching back to Alpha.
$16$. The first of its kind, it's functionality is later passed on to another with a less religious name.
$17$. Synonymous with two damage in magic.
$18$. Romanian vampires in Ravnica?
$19$. "I'll have what she's having!" Break out the rulebook for this Yoked Ox.
$24$. Sort of like The One Ring of Tolkien's world (I guess that makes Karn Sauron)
$25$. Don't rock the boat!
$28$. Oh I could just go on and on about this card: it's so spectacular and powerful--who doesn't love drawing cards--and...
$29$. This was his first appearance; it isn't until years later that we learn it's actually a mispronounciation of the real name!
$31$. When you cast this card from Alpha, your opponent will likely look like the depiction in the art.
$32$. It's no lion but it is a cat that enjoys savannahs.
$33$. Non-artifact? Check! Non-black? Check! Bye bye!
$35$. Its mere approach sends Jeskai decks running.
$36$. Bruce Willis' favorite card.
$37$. IT'S NO ICY!...it's no icy
$38$. Cloudy with a chance of meteor shower.
$39$. Recently made playable in legacy for the first time ever.

### Vertical

$1$. Meaning fate, this card was later color shifted into blue.
$2$. Paradoxically can be used against Soulless One.
$3$. A member of magic's creepiest creature type, this one had the most success.
$4$. This card really 'got it!' until the rules change stopped damage from using the stack.
$5$. Great! First I had to go help out on the farm, now I have to go on a stupid journey to a new land!
$6$. THE magic card!
$8$. Another? Don't mind if I do!
$9$. Sometimes 8-down is just a reeally expensive (\$) one of these.
$11$. At least neither of us get to do anyth-wait that's not fair! And what's going on in this art?
$14$. Ooh that creature looks fun! I'll take one too.
$15$. An Icelandic glacial flood that is a bigger version of 36-across.
$20$. Out of the blackness and stench of the engulfing swamp came `___`
$21$. I'll drag you out of your ivory tower and put you in my torture device!
$22$. The most powerful card in Legacy
$23$. If you've got a hunch on this card, you should follow it.
$26$. He exercises his right to were clothes!
$27$. Patrick Sullivan refers to this Khans of Tarkir card as "full retail".
$30$. Upset because this card was made obselete in Born of the Gods? Take its successor's advice.
$34$. Another place where you can commonly find 32-across.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Got 'em all! Credit to Zerris for #6 which somehow didn't occur to me, and to Gatherer's regex function which I admit I used to find four or five of 'em.

> Across:
>  1: Kird Ape
>  7: Damnation
>  10: Cancel
>  12: Grapeshot
>  13: Elvish Mystic
>  16: Wrath of God
>  17: Shock
>  18: Moroii
>  19: Spellskite
>  24: Mirari
>  25: Capsize
>  28: Gush
>  29: Gideon Jura
>  31: Mind Twist
>  32: Wild Nacatl
>  33: Terror
>  35: Siege Rhino
>  36: Armageddon
>  37: Ring of Gix
>  38: Starstorm
>  39: Land Tax
>
>  Vertical:
>  1: Kismet
>  2: Remove Soul
>  3: Psychatog
>  4: Mogg Fanatic
>  5: Path to Exile
>  6: Black Lotus
>  8: Time Walk
>  9: Explore
>  11: Stasis
>  14: Clone
>  15: Jokulhaups
>  20: White Knight
>  21: Black Vise
>  22: Brainstorm
>  23: Intuition
>  26: Werebear
>  27: Utter End
>  30: Infest
>  34: Taiga

Comment: Seems that you manage to make all of my mtg puzzles look easy, even the non-math ones. Did you omit 34-down on purpose? And out of curiosity, did you manage most of these at first glance or did they take some research?

Comment: Missing 34-down was a transcription error, fixed. Here's the ones that required research (mostly a trip to Gatherer): 3, 18, 19, 25, 1 (just to check I was right), 30. Most of them were pretty much instant, but a few (12, 28, 14) required either some thinking, or waiting until the letters lined up to give me a clue.

Comment: To clarify, it's not a bad thing that I got most of them quickly, I know a *lot* of Magic cards, they were intuitive in a good crosswordy way.

Comment: I must admit, #5 was my least favorite. For a card that sees so much play, I was at a loss for a pun or something fun to do. And upon further research, it seems my theory that a pw is on the art was debunked. I'll update the clue accordingly

Comment: New clue makes it easy, and done!

Comment: Without the clue #5 could be found on gatherer with the regex m/.+a.+h.+o.+e$/ . it had 56 matches but you can go through them pretty fast.

Comment: @IvoBeckers I realized belatedly that I messed up my regex, which is why _a_h_o____e wasn't enough to find it.

Answer (score 0):

A few more:

> 7: Damnation
>
>  6: Black Lotus

Comment: You sure you've got those numbers right? Those two answers don't fit on the same board. Edit: I think you meant 6 instead of 8.

Comment: Fixed. I really want 8 to be twincast, but that doesn't play nice with 16.

Comment: Got 8, and thus 9.

Comment: Oh, durr, I had a T at the end of 8 instead of a K.  That was obvious.